convertir un string a float con un foramto por defecto
Tengo un aforamto que recibo de mi BD viene en este formato
"$ 10,000.00"

Necesito sumar varios datos, todos tienen este formato lo que hago es quitar la coma y me da: "10000.00" de tipo STRING; hago el parseo a float, lo que quita los decimales y me da como resultado:
10000
Y yo lo necesito
10000.00 como tipo float
    datosFiltrados.forEach(row => {
        
        const importeSinComas = row.Importe.replace(/\$|,/g, '');

       
        const montoNumero = parseFloat(importeSinComas)

       
        const newRow = {
            ...row,
            MontoApagar: montoNumero
        };

        
        rowsToAdd.add(newRow);
    });


En javascript el tipo number tiene tanto enteros como números de coma flotante. Si de alguna manera quieres asegurarte de tener siempre un número de coma flotante, puedes multiplicar por 1.0 (lo cual no afecta el tipo de la variable).
He preparado una función que quita el formato paso a paso y devuelve siempre un número, con un pequeño ejemplo:


function quitarFormato(importe) {
  let importeSinComas = importe.replace(/\$|,/g, '').trim();
  let montoNumero = parseFloat(importeSinComas);
  return(montoNumero * 1.0);
}

let importe1 = "$ 10,000.00";
let importe2 = "$ 10,000.00";
let importe3 = "$ 10,000.25";

let total = quitarFormato(importe1) + quitarFormato(importe2) + quitarFormato(importe3);

console.log(total);



Para producción, se podría reducir a algo como:


function quitarFormato(importe) {
  return(parseFloat(importe.replace(/\$|,/g, '').trim()) * 1.0);
}

let importe1 = "$ 10,000.00";
let importe2 = "$ 10,000.00";
let importe3 = "$ 10,000.25";

let total = quitarFormato(importe1) + quitarFormato(importe2) + quitarFormato(importe3);

console.log(total);



Para mayor claridad, incluyo esta nota de la documentación de parseFloat():

Note: JavaScript does not have the distinction of "floating point numbers" and "integers" on the language level. parseInt() and parseFloat() only differ in their parsing behavior, but not necessarily their return values. For example, parseInt("42") and parseFloat("42") would return the same value: a Number 42.

Mi traducción libre:

Nota: JavaScript no hace distinción entre "números de coma flotante" y "enteros" a nivel del lenguaje. Las funciones parseInt() y parseFloat() solo difieren en el comportamiento de parseo, pero no necesariamente en sus valores de retorno. Por ejemplo, parseInt("42")  y parseFloat("42") retornarían el mismo valor: un tipo Number con valor 42.


parseFloat(n) * 1.0 es redundante y no tiene mayor efecto. La pregunta no es sobre convertir un string a float. Es lo inverso, de float a string pero por defecto


No es posible establecer un formato por defecto en javascript

En Javascript todos los números son del tipo Number (excepto el BigInt), el cual es un primitivo, por lo que no es posible sobrescribir sus propiedades y por ende aplicar algún "truco" como sobrescribir toString en los prototype

Javascript almacena internamente los números como float, tanto para números enteros y decimales. Y float es una forma de representar un número en una computadora, está forma está estandarizada en IEEE 754

En las ciencias 10000 tiene una connotación distinta a 10000.00, por el tema de las cifras significativas. Esto aporta información sobre la precisión del número.


En cambio, float tiene una precisión definida entre 15 y 17 números en su parte decimal. En el siguiente ejemplo se ve como javascript trunca el valor a 17 decimales.


console.log("0.1234567890123456789")
console.log( 0.1234567890123456789 )




En javascript (tal como en matemáticas) 10000 es igual 10000.00, además que la connotación de precisión no es relevante (como se explica en el punto anterior)



console.log(10000 === 10000.00)



De todo lo anterior, queda claro que no es posible cambiar el comportamiento del float (punto 1 y 2) y menos su naturaleza, ya que dejaría de ser float (punto  3, 4 y 5), es decir, no puedes querer un 10000.00 pero siga siendo float.
Debes separar lo que es el valor almacenado de su representación en pantalla, no solo para los números, sino que para fechas y cualquier tipo de dato. Son cosas distintas y deben manejarse de forma distinta. El valor se usa para operar con él y otros elementos, mientras que la representación es para mostrar al usuario dicho valor, en cuyo caso le aplicas un formato a tu conveniencia.
Pero hay que tener claro que dicho formato tiene siempre como salida un String, y no hay problema con eso, porque solo es para mostrarlo
Para tu caso, lo más simple es utilizar toFixed(2)


const montoNumero = 10000.00;
console.log(montoNumero);
console.log(montoNumero.toFixed(2));



